# DataModelSelection on list exposed via EntityQuery

Tags: jsf, seam

Is it possible to have support for enabling DataModelSelection on a list page paginated via EntityQuery? (All the examples load the list by performing a query on the @Factory method). But, I would like to re-use the existing pagination mechanism and just enable the ability to support DataModelSelection on it.

I am also assuming that DataModelSelection is capable of tracking a single row in a List, **how do we extend this to support a certain action (say deletion, activation ...) of multiple rows.**

I am a newbie and would appreciate any help on this topic. I have already gone through the samples shipped as part of Seam (booking, message).

I have already posted this in seam users [forum](http://seamframework.org/Community/DataModelSelectionOnListExposedViaEntityQuery), but I am yet to get a response

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have solved this issue by now but these two code snippets might help a bit

[html code (jsf file)](http://www.pastie.org/2048640)

[a method in the bean that handles the action from the jsf](http://www.pastie.org/2048663)